# Unable to update SQL Server database with value from textbox in gridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have just joined stackoverflow as a relatively novice user of visual studio, with the hope that someone might be able to help answer a question to a problem I'm having.

I'm sure it's quite simple, but at the moment I have a Gridview which is bound to a table from our SQL Server.

My issue I'm having is with the gridview, which was generated with the help of the in-built wizard. My update SQL statement is a custom one, which is quite simply:

```
UPDATE SMCsummove
SET SubmitQty = @Textbox1 * - 1, HasBeenEdited = 'Y'
WHERE (SMCPOinteger = @SMCPOinteger) AND (SMCproduct = @PartNo)
```

Now being a novice, I am not quite sure if I am doing this right, but @Textbox1 is the value that the user enters as a new value to update the table with, after they have clicked the autogenerated 'edit' button. Quite simply once they have clicked the 'update' button, the gridview reverts back to the original value that was there in the SubmitQty column.

If anyone can shed some light or point out any massive oversights, that would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Need to see more of the code from the gridview to know for sure, but it looks like a postback is occurring and this is causing your gridview to bind again and be reset.

I'm pretty new to this as well and what I have found works for gridviews is to have a pageload event like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            bindGridView();
        }

    }
```

Then have a separate statement for the binding (this is one that I uses:

```
private void bindGridView()
   {
            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
            string selectSQL = String.Format("SQL Statement here");
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            adapter.Fill(ds, "Review");

            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();

   }
```

You may find you have to call the gridbind as well after updating records to repopulate the gridview with the updated values.